# How to dynamically highlight changing numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mark.js

I have been searching for days now.

I have some random numbers that are generated automatically with crunch function on 3 minute interval:

```
setInterval(crunch, 180000);
```

then I can nicely highlight the return random numbers with mark.js:

```
$(function() {
        var mark = function() {
            // Read the keyword
            var keyword = $("input[name='keyword']").val();
            var keyword2 = $("input[name='keyword2']").val();
            // Remove previous marked elements and mark
            // the new keyword inside the context
            $(".context").unmark({
                done: function() {
                    $(".context").mark(keyword).mark(keyword2, {
                        className: 'secondary'
                    });
                }
            });
        };
        $("input[name^='keyword']").on("input", mark);
    });
```

My problem is when the second lot of new numbers are generated the highlight goes away - please can you kindly share a way how I can make them stay highlighted forever?

Here is my working fiddle on a 3 min interval:

https://jsfiddle.net/heybubbles/eztgy7j9/12/

min: 1
max: 100
results: 100

I tend to search for the highlighted number after generation not sure how to make
it search on generation apologies.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change the keyword after the re-generating numbers it will re-highlight it. Don't appear to be a way to trigger mark manually and you have the change the input for it to re trigger, rather than use marksjs why not just do something like this

[mark.js trigger event from selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256705/mark-js-trigger-event-from-selection)

Comment: thanks Patrick, I have been playing around with this for a few days not any closer to getting it to work, as mentioned I would like to select a number or input it and that choosen number will be hightlighted when it appears in the forever changing random results.

Comment: I added the code snippet you kindly pointed me too and added this.             ```<div data-answer="context" class="context answers" id="result"></div> ```

Comment: please can you kindly share a bin or pen of my example otherwise this should not be considered as a correct answer as the result is static not dynamic. thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry will do ASAP I am away at the moment so will do as soon as i can

Comment: Hey just one other thing that has been puzzling me... please can you make the numbers align nicely in columns and rows. I guess if you can do that I will create another overflow and assign it to you? many thanks in advance Patrick!

Comment: No worries about the number formatting I was able to figure that out - alignment is good for me, just a working example of the main question would be greatly appreciated Patrik! cheers Bubs

Comment: sorry for the late reply, here is a working example that will re highlight when you click generate every time https://jsfiddle.net/PatrickHume/1hn05jox/2/, i hope this helps

Comment: Awesome Patrick. really awesome. thanks mate!

Comment: np glad i was able to help :)